# Parse error php Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, php-parse-error

I have this function on my code, and give me this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting ')' on line 25
```

I cant find the error maybe you can see what I can't D:

```
public function InsertHero()
    {
        $this->load->view('Header');
        $this->load->view('HeroForm');
        $this->load->view('Footer');

        $data = array(
        'Name' -> $this -> input -> post('nick'), //this is the line 25
        'Power' -> $this -> input -> post('superpower'),
        'Phone' -> $this -> input -> post('phone'),
        'Email' -> $this -> input -> post('mail'),
        'Category' -> $this -> input -> post('category_id')
        );
        $this->model_heroes->insert($data);
        redirect(base_url());
    }
```

Comment: hash array syntax is `$data = array('Name' => $this->input->post('nick'));`

Comment: And here is your source to learn how to make arrays in php. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax

Comment: -_-'' thank you I forgot that ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple error, you have used the operator for classes/objects (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR is **->**) in your array declaration, when you should have used the T_DOUBLE_ARROW **=>** operator.

Therefore your array should look like;

```
$data = array('Name' => $this->input->post('nick'));
```

For reference [PHP operators](http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php)

Answer (score 1):

Per Rooney's comment, you do an array like this:

```
array( "foo" => "bar");
```

Not this:

```
array( "foo" -> "bar");
```